# Why is ForEach not changing my Foreground color correctly in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I am trying to make a simple Todo app and I'm trying to implement a feature where if I click on a row, the foreground color will be change. However, I have two problems, first when I toggle the boolean value in for my core data attribute, nothing happens on the front end. The value changes true/false but the foreground color is not changing.

Second, when I instead use a simple @State boolean value, ALL the list row foreground colors change instead of just the row I tapped on.

```
import SwiftUI
import ChameleonFramework

struct ItemView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @StateObject var category: Category
    @State private var showAddItemView = false
    @State private var text = ""
    @State var testBool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                List {
                    ForEach(searchResults) { item in
                        
                        Text(item.unwrappedTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(item.unwrappedDone ? .red : .blue)
//                            .foregroundColor(Color(ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: UIColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor), returnFlat: true)))
                            .onTapGesture {
                                print(item.unwrappedTitle)
                                item.done.toggle()
                                print(item.done)
                                try? moc.save()
                            }
                            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor)))
                        //                            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor).darken(byPercentage: 0.5)))
                        //                            .listRowBackground(Color(HexColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor)))
                        
                    }
```

So using the Core Data variable `item.done.toggle` does nothing to change the foreground color when toggled but it does switch between true/false. Alternatively, using the `@State var testBool` changes ALL the rows instead of just the one tapped.

I want to tap on a row and have it change color on only that row.

I made `searchResults` equal to `category.itemArray` for purposes of search and filtering.

```
    var searchResults: [Item] {
        if text.isEmpty {
            return category.itemArray
        } else {
            return category.itemArray.filter { Item in
                Item.title!.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is searchResult ? I don’t see it’s definition.

Comment: I've just added the searchResult to the question. Apologies.

Comment: So, `Category` is a Core Data entity?

Comment: May be, you miss a @FetchRequest variable so SwiftUI know that date from database has changed ?

Comment: Yes I have Category and Item as entities. In this problem, I have a list of Items within a category. Also when I test the boolean toggle in a Core Data tracker app on my Macbook, the value is changing.

Comment: But this issue is that change is not published by the Core Data entity. You either need to use an `@FetchRequest`, or use an `NSFetchedResultsController` as in [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993532/7129318). The `@StateObject` doesn't magically change the underlying class; it just reacts to it.

Comment: My ```@FetchRequest``` is located in my Category file. It is a One-to-Many relationship (Category-Item). The when I track the changes in Core Data Lab (a Mac app) it shows the the boolean is changing when toggled. The result just doesn't show on the user screen. Basically like the change is only happening on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

So I asked another question using mock data on another post and that helped me solve this. Basically, I just needed to make a subview

```
struct ExtractedView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @State var testBool = false
    
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(item.unwrappedTitle)
            .foregroundColor(testBool ? .red : .green)
            .foregroundColor(Color(ContrastColorOf(backgroundColor: UIColor(hexString: item.unwrappedColor), returnFlat: true)))
            .onTapGesture {
                print(item.unwrappedTitle)
                item.done.toggle()
                print(item.unwrappedDone)
                testBool.toggle()
                try? moc.save()
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor(hexString: item.unwrappedColor)))
    }
}
```

And here is the ExtractedView using ForEach..

```
import SwiftUI
import ChameleonFramework

struct ItemView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var moc
    @StateObject var category: Category
    @State private var showAddItemView = false
    @State private var text = ""
//    @State var testBool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                
                List {
                    ForEach(searchResults) { item in
                        
                        ExtractedView(item: item)
                        //                            .listRowBackground(Color(UIColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor).darken(byPercentage: 0.5)))
                        //                            .listRowBackground(Color(HexColor(hexString: category.unwrappedColor)))
                        
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItem)
```

Comment: Here is the link for the formatted question I asked... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72069996/why-does-foreach-not-work-with-ontapgesture-modifier-correctly-in-swiftui